Trying to persist docker container data
I want to Persist my sqlite database between container restarts and new image pulls
Hi,
I have this docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage
    container_name: thecontainername
    volumes:
      - ./app.db:/prisma/app.db
    restart: always
  watchtower:
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    container_name: watchtower
    labels:
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=false"
    environment:
      - REPO_USER=${DOCKERHUB_USER}
      - REPO_PASS=${DOCKERHUB_PASS}
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: --cleanup --interval 120 --debug
    restart: always

Sqlite database is persisted between container restarts but not when pulling a new image manually via command or automatically with watchtower.
How could this be resolved ?

Is app.db the database, and is it a file, rather than a directory?

I can answer the above: SQLite uses a file-based DB, so yes, app.db is the database.

@BMitch yes it is a file, I also tried a volume with a directory containing the database file but it didn't work

Please show your second test. Also show the output of docker diff before deleting the container. And minimize the example, watchtower is a distraction from your problem.

On the host system, does the app.db file exist?  Can you see its contents using something like sqlite3 app.db?  Do you in fact have the correct path in the container; the application is expecting to find the database in exactly /prisma/app.db?

@DavidMaze On the host system, generated app.db is an empty directory (Docker allows volumes pointing directly to files?). When I try to put app.db in a directory in the project and create a volume with it (- ./data:/prisma/db) in my docker-compose file, the generated "data" directory is also empty.

@BMith
docker diff result:
C /usr
C /usr/src
C /usr/src/myproject
C /usr/src/myproject/prisma
C /usr/src/myproject/prisma/app.db
A /prisma
A /prisma/app.db

That sounds to me like the container-side path (/prisma/app.db) is wrong.  Given the last result, does it need to be /usr/src/myproject/prisma/app.db instead?  If you're trying to mount a single file into a container, it must already exist, or else Docker will create an empty directory; it is often easier to bind-mount directories than individual files.

Ok it works with ./app.db:/usr/src/myproject/prisma/app.db.
Thank you all

From the follow up, it appears you were mounting the wrong path inside the container. This is shown with the files that have been changed in the container filesystem (displayed with docker diff) not matching the path of the volume mount.
Typically, you do not want to mount mutable files directly in the container, and instead want to mount the entire directory. This is because many tools that modify files do so by creating a new temporary file, and then renaming it to overwrite the existing file. That process creates a new inode, and volume mounts are bound to the inode, resulting in any changes inside the container, or outside the container, not being reflected on the other side or between container restarts.
